# kernel module problem in commercial software

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, insmod, commercial-application

The security software I'm building contains a kernel module.
because the kernel must process the packet.

Do not use DKMS because it is commercial software.

If the kernel version goes up, insmod doesn't work.

What should I do? Do you have a good idea?

Comment: The versioning is there for a reason - modules compiled for one version of the kernel may not work for other versions of the kernel. If you really insist then can force load the module with `--force` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't load the modules dynamically then another option to load the modules is making it as part of the kernel. Refer the following link :

http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/system/kernel-pkg.html